# Libevent writes to the socket only after second buffer_write

Tags: c++, network-programming, libevent

Libevent is great and I love it so far. However, on a echo server, the write only sends to the socket on a second write. My writing is from another thread, a pump thread that talks to a db and does some minimal data massaging.

I verified this by setting up a callback for the write:

```
bufferevent_setcb( GetBufferEvent(), DataAvailable, DataWritten, HandleSocketError, this );
```

calling bufferevent_flush( m_bufferEvent, EV_READ|EV_WRITE, BEV_NORMAL ) doesn't seem to have any effect.

Here is the setup, just in case I blew it somewhere. I have dramatically simplified the overhead in my code base in order to obtain some help. This includes initialization of sockets, my thread init, etc. This is a multi-threaded app, so there may be some problem there. I start with this:

```
m_LibEventInstance = event_base_new();
evthread_use_windows_threads();
m_listener = evconnlistener_new_bind( m_LibEventInstance, 
         OnAccept, 
         this,
         LEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE | LEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_EXEC | LEV_OPT_REUSEABLE, 
         -1,// no maximum number of backlog connections
         (struct sockaddr*)&ListenAddress, socketSize );

   if (!m_listener) {
          perror("Couldn't create listener");
          return false;
   }
   evconnlistener_set_error_cb( m_listener, OnSystemError );
```

AFAIK, this is copy and paste from samples so it should work. My OnAccept does the following:

```
void  OnAccept( evconnlistener* listenerObj, evutil_socket_t newConnectionId, sockaddr* ClientAddr, int socklen, void* context )
{
    // We got a new connection! Set up a bufferevent for it. 
    struct event_base*  base = evconnlistener_get_base( listenerObj );
    struct bufferevent* bufferEvent = bufferevent_socket_new( base, newConnectionId, BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE );

   bufferevent_setcb( GetBufferEvent(), DataAvailable, DataWritten, 
                                   HandleSocketError, this );

  // We have to enable it before our callbacks will be called. 
  bufferevent_enable( GetBufferEvent(), EV_READ | EV_WRITE );

  DisableNagle( m_connectionId );
}
```

Now, I simply respond to data coming in and store it in a buffer for later processing. This is a multi-threaded application, so I will process the data later, massage it, or return a response to the client.

```
void     DataAvailable( struct bufferevent* bufferEventObj, void* arg )
{
const U32   MaxBufferSize = 8192;
   MyObj*   This = (MyObj*) arg;
   U8          data[ MaxBufferSize ];
   size_t      numBytesreceived;

   /* Read 8k at a time and send it to all connected clients. */
   while( 1 )
   {
      numBytesreceived = bufferevent_read( bufferEventObj, data, sizeof( data ) );
      if( numBytesreceived <= 0 ) // nothing to send
      {
         break;
      }

      if( This )
      {
         This->OnDataReceived( data, numBytesreceived );
      }
   }
}
```

the last thing that happens, once I look up my data, package into a buffer, and then on a threaded timeslice I do this:

```
bufferevent_write( m_bufferEvent, buffer, bufferOffset );
```

It never, ever sends the first time. To get it to send, I have to send a second buffer full of data.

This behavior is killing me and I have spent a lot of hours on it. Any ideas?

//-------------------------------------------------------

I finally gave up and used this hack instead... there just was not enough info to tell me why libevent wasn't writing to the socket. This works just fine.

```
int result = send( m_connectionId, (const char* )buffer, bufferOffset, 0 );
```

Comment: Just FYI: the libevent mailing list is very friendly. I've debugged several problems with their help; so if anything, I would ask there as well.

Answer (score -1):

I met the problem, too! I spent one day on this problem. At last, I solved it.

When the thread you call `event_base_dispatch`, it will be asleep until any semaphore wakes it up. So, when it sleeps, you call `bufferevent_write`, the bufferevent's fd adds to the event list, but it won't be epoll until next time. So you must send semaphore to wake up the dispatch thread after you called `bufferevent_write`. The way you can use is set up an event bind pair socket and add it to `event_base`. Then send 1 byte anytime when you need to wake up the disptach thread.